# How to extract entire code from clearcase for a given label?

Tags: windows, perl, clearcase, cleartool

What would be the best way to extract code from clearcase for a give label. Planning to do this in perl first then in GUI based model.

Whenever release is made, release label is applied on all files. Once tested, This script should copy/extract all the files from clearcase and upload it to another server.

Environment: Windows.

any insight would be of great help.

1. Create a snapshot/dynamic view with config spec,  element * Label. Then use windows command to copy.
2. tar cf tarfile $(ct find -a -ver 'lbtype(Label)' -print) , need to find similar one for windows env. No Cygwin.

Comment: script will take Label and vob name as input.

Answer (score 0):

If the label is applied on all elements,  then create a view with the right config spec is the easiest way to access the code referenced by that label

```
element * mylabel
```